# In gensim with pretrained model, wmdistance is working well, but n_similarity is not

Tags: gensim

I have calculated distances between two sentences using wmdistance() funtion of gensim with pre-trained model

Now, I want to similarity between them and tried with  n_similarity() funnction, but keyerror occured

keyerror : word not in vacabulary

This shows  screenshoot of error example
[image: screenshoot of error example]

Anyone have got idea on this, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get an error that a word is not in the vocabulary, it means the word is not in that model.

Any attempt to look it up will generate a `KeyError`, to let you know you are trying to get a word-vector that isn't there.

You should filter your lists-of-tokens, before passing them to `n_similarity()`, to only include valid words.

Of course, that means you can't get a meaningful result about the word `'selfie'`. It's unknown nonsense to the model, as if you asked for the word `'asruhfglaiwurfliuawiufsdfsdfs'`.

Comment: If n_similarity() can't get a meaningful result about the word 'selfie', then how is it possible with wmdistance() ?

Comment: `wmdistance()` is silently ignoring out-of-vocabulary words, as you can see in the source code: https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/d952a51ee11180bd0fe984470218757d19db32bd/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py#L719